# Understanding ESP8266 Assembly Errors in Arduino IDE on upgrade from Boards Package v2.x to 3.x

Tags: assembly, compiler-errors, arduino, esp8266, arduino-esp8266

[Updated post: I originally had a broader question, but have narrowed down my problem to the change from using ESP8266 Boards Package v2.x to ESP8266 Boards Package v3.x]

On reinstalling the Arduino IDE on a new computer, I tried going with the latest versions of everything, but I've found that moving from ESP8266 Boards Package 2.x to 3.x is triggering essentially meaningless error messages which are making it impossible to either search for possible solutions, or help me decide where to look.  There's hundreds of lines of errors, but they're all like this:

```
/var/folders/9_/nlhqn4y90zl54rhtm87_x0gc0000gn/T//ccwAAS5l.s:19400: Error: junk at end of line, first unrecognized character valued 0x9
/var/folders/9_/nlhqn4y90zl54rhtm87_x0gc0000gn/T//ccwAAS5l.s:19401: Error: bad register name:   a2
/var/folders/9_/nlhqn4y90zl54rhtm87_x0gc0000gn/T//ccwAAS5l.s:19401: Error: junk at end of line, first unrecognized character valued 0x9
/var/folders/9_/nlhqn4y90zl54rhtm87_x0gc0000gn/T//ccwAAS5l.s:19412: Error: bad register name:   a2
/var/folders/9_/nlhqn4y90zl54rhtm87_x0gc0000gn/T//ccwAAS5l.s:19412: Error: junk at end of line, first unrecognized character valued 0x9
/var/folders/9_/nlhqn4y90zl54rhtm87_x0gc0000gn/T//ccwAAS5l.s:19413: Error: bad register name:   a3
```

Or this:

```
/var/folders/9_/nlhqn4y90zl54rhtm87_x0gc0000gn/T//ccwAAS5l.s:22064: Error: operation combines symbols in different segments
/var/folders/9_/nlhqn4y90zl54rhtm87_x0gc0000gn/T//ccwAAS5l.s:55163: Error: operation combines symbols in different segments
/var/folders/9_/nlhqn4y90zl54rhtm87_x0gc0000gn/T//ccwAAS5l.s:55203: Error: operation combines symbols in different segments
```

I've tried looking for that file (ccwAAS5l.s) on the computer, but can't find it.

There's nothing in any of the errors that look even closely like anything in my code, or any of my dependencies.

Some demo sketches compile, so it's not a global issue.  There's clearly an incompatibility in my code - and I know that the ESP8266 Boards Package upgrade to v3 does introduce some breaking changes (https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/releases).

I'm at a loss for how to use any of this to track down the source of my problems.  It'd be fine if it could point to errors in my code... but I've not got a clue as to how to track down assembler errors.  I can't even post any sensible snippets here, because my code runs to thousands of lines and don't know which are relevant.

Any pointers on what this error means, or where to start looking for a solution?

Very many thanks!

Comment: `ccwAAS5l.s` looks like a random temporary name GCC generated from a C file, which it then runs the assembler on.  (And deletes after attempting to build).  `gcc -save-temps` can save the compiler output, and looking at earlier error messages should tell you which C source file this `.s` was generated from.  I'd suspect you might have inline asm for the wrong architecture (perhaps due to wrong `#define` macros?) since you're getting asm with register names like `a2`.  IDK if that should be appropriate for the Tensilica CPU in that board (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ESP8266)

Comment: Thanks Pete.  Not sure I can configure the Arduino IDE (using v2.0.0-rc9) to use `gcc -save-temps`.  I tried turning on verbose output during compile, but unfortunately there are (presumably) too many lines and so I can't see what file it was processing before the error arises.  Can't see a way to get the Arduino IDE to give me any more - and I worry that trying to compile manually using GCC is more likely to introduce new errors just due to my unfamiliarity with manual compilation.  Any workarounds anyone knows to get Arduino IDE to show my the complete compilation output?

Comment: Managed to copy/paste the output as it was written, so captured the full verbose Arduino IDE compiler output.  Unfortunately the .s filename doesn't appear anywhere in the output, so hasn't given me the pointer we were hoping for.
Is there an easy way to run `gcc -save-temps` with or without the Arduino IDE?  Last time I tried getting Arduino code to compile outside of the Arduino IDE I never managed to get it working, after days of trying...

Comment: *Without* the IDE, yes, very easy, just add that option to a normal GCC command line in a terminal window.  Also you can get the full error messages, if necessary by redirecting stderr to a file, so you can see which .c it was compiling and any warnings from that.  If your IDE can show you what GCC command it's running from what directory, you can use that command as a starting point.  If the output is huge, perhaps cut down the file to make a [mcve].  e.g. save the original, then start deleting stuff wholesale until you get a small set of error.  (Or if no errors, undo some deletion.)

Comment: Thanks @PeterCordes - re-using the GCC command from the previous Verbose output and running it the command line works great.  So I've added -save-temps, though not managed to find much of use in the output file.  My only possible clue is that I get an extra line in the error now: `Error: unknown opcode or format name 'zn16esp8266webserver24esp8266webservertempl5'`, which does correspond to a library I'm using.  I've run out of time to probe further today, but have started removing some of the bigger external libraries to eliminate some possibilities.  I'll keep going tomorrow.  Thanks!

Comment: So good news - I've solved it.  Thanks @PeterCordes for your help which pointed me in the right direction.
I managed to find the .s file and match the line numbers - nothing too obvious, and when I first skimmed a few found errors seemed to link to hundreds of different files and functions.  But starting at the top tried to fix the first error, which basically was trying to do too much in an IRAM_ATTR function, which presumably messed with memory somewhere?!  Not entirely clear, but commenting out a couple of lines of my error logging code fixed it all!  :)

Comment: Weird, IDK why that would lead to a cascade of error messages.  If you ever run into a similar problem in a different context, maybe that'll be a clue that the real cause was something else.  Or maybe just some weird quirk of the toolchain.  I'd kind of expect trying to do too much in one function to be a problem at run-time, or for linking if there was some kind of size limit, not for assemble-time.

Comment: Thanks yeah I had the same thought - felt like that should throw a run-time error rather than compile-time - but assumed maybe the compiler was cleverer than I expected??  Or maybe you're right and it's actually caused by something else, but this change did enough to make that go away?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The suggestions from @PeterCordes in the comments on my original question helped me find the cause - I'd recommend others with similar issues follow that advice.

The result wasn't very obvious, but thought worth sharing some examples.  The first entry in the compiler error was:

```
KDHomeNode.ino.s: Assembler messages:
KDHomeNode.ino.s:4896: Error: bad register name:    sp
KDHomeNode.ino.s:4896: Error: junk at end of line, first unrecognized character valued 0x9
```

Once I eventually managed to find the `.ino.s` file, and went to line 4896, I found the following (where the relevant line is `addi  sp, sp, -32`:

```
_ZN7Buttons8onChangeEv:
.LVL430:
.LFB4255:
    .file 27 "/Users/dave/Documents/Development/KDHome/Arduino/KDHomeNode/IOButtons.h"
    .loc 27 95 90 is_stmt 1 view -0
    .loc 27 96 7 view .LVU1293
    .loc 27 95 90 is_stmt 0 view .LVU1294
    addi    sp, sp, -32
.LCFI150:
    s32i.n  a12, sp, 24
```

Not at all clear what was wrong from that line, but scrolling up suggested my IOButtons.h file, and perhaps the onChange() event?  The only seemingly notable thing about that function was that it was a callback for an interrupt.  Looking at the reference for Interrupts (https://arduino-esp8266.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference.html#interrupts) had a note about potential issues if playing with memory within those functions, and I realised that I'd inadvertently added some logging capabilities within that function.  Not a lot, just the following - but the `printDebug` function itself does quite a bit of `strncpy` and `Serial.print()`ing

```
          char pin_str[3];
          char press_time_str[12];
          itoa(_pin, pin_str, 10);
          ltoa(press_time, press_time_str, 10);
          printDebug("Button ", pin_str, " pressed (", press_time_str, "ms)");
```

Anyway, by commenting those lines out the whole thing compiles perfectly now, even after adding back all of the other code / third party libraries / etc that I'd tried removing yesterday.

Perhaps the strangest thing, I thought, was that there were hundreds if not thousands of lines of compiler errors, spread across over 168,000 lines in the `.ino.s` file, referring to all sorts of different functions - but fixing only the first managed to resolve the rest!  So I think good advice to anyone - don't be disheartened if it looks like there's massive issues that will take forever to work through.  Just start at the top, and the rest might resolve themselves.

Thanks again to Peter for his help in finding the cause.

Comment: `first unrecognized character valued 0x9` makes me wonder if there are some unprintable ASCII codes ending up in the `.s` file.  And maybe it's not really `sp` that it doesn't like, but `"sp\x09"`.  I don't know how that would get into the compiler's asm output, though, except perhaps via a compiler bug like a memory overwrite of its register-name string.  I assume `sp` is a valid register name for your Tensilica CPU, and instructions like `addi    sp, sp, -32` still appear in the asm output for the working version.